# React Array converted to object when passed as a prop to SFC

Tags: reactjs

I have a react function and I am passing an array of objects as a prop. When the component renders, the array is nested into an object of the same name.

Why is it being nested? And can I do something to coerce it back to an array?

Here is the code (and a link to a pen (https://codepen.io/bluesixty/pen/PJQKVq?editors=0010):

```
const tags = [
      {
        name: 'ios',
        link: '',
      },
      {
        name: 'ANDROID',
        link: '',
      },
      {
        name: 'REACT',
        link: '',
      },
      {
        name: 'javascript',
        link: '',
      },
    ]


const App = tagList => {

    return (
      <div>
        This is a React component!
        <ul>
          {tagList.tagList.map((tag, i) => (
            <li>
              {tag.name}
            </li>
        ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }


ReactDOM.render(
    <App tagList={tags}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Removing the second tagList in the .map fails with 'tagList.map is not a function'. Which is true, it is an object now????

```
{tagList.map((tag, i) => (
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A functional component receives `props` as the first argument, so the correct code is:

```
const App = props => {

    return (
      <div>
        This is a React component!
        <ul>
          {props.tagList.map((tag, i) => (
            <li>
              {tag.name}
            </li>
        ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It can also be written like this:

```
const App = ({ tagList }) => (
  <div>
    This is a React component!
    <ul>
      {tagList.map(({ name }, i) => (
        <li>
          {name}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Changing to props.taglist.map fails with 'props is undefined'. Changing the argument to ({ tagList }) did work but why do the extra brackets turn in back into an array?

Comment: @bluesixty Not sure why you got "props is undefined". In general, you pass all props as the first argument. If you specify `<App a='foo' b='bar' />`, then the first argument is an object like `{a: 'foo', b: 'bar', ...}`. As for `({ tagList }) => {...}`, it's short for `props => {let tagList = props.tagList; ...}`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScriptJavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment.

Comment: I see, undefined was my fault, forgot to change the arg to props. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4):

Your 1st question:

> Why is it being nested?

When you pass data to any React component, you pass it as 'props'. In your case, the data you want to pass is your `tags` array populated with objects.

The function defining the App component has `props` as its parameter. When you pass your argument to it, you pass it as an **object argument**, i.e. props is an **object** containing the props you pass to a component.

That's why if you had a plain variable:

```
let greeting = 'Hello World'
```

And passed it as props:

```
<App content={greeting}/>
```

The props object would look like this:

```
props = {
   greeting: 'Hello World'
}
```

and you'd access it in the App component function as such:

```
{props.content}
```

The variable passed as an argument is an object parameter for the function.

Your 2nd question:

> And can I do something to coerce it back to an array?

Yes, you can. Within the App component:

```
 const tags = [];
  Object.keys(props).forEach(function(prop) {
    tags.push(...props[prop]);
  });

  console.log(tags); // now an array with your tags
```

However, you don't need to. You can use `props.tagList` as mentioned in the answer above.

Hope that clears it up for others.